# what is the best function to check a list of proxies: fsockopen, curl or socket?

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I have a list of proxies with this format IP:Port.

I need to connect to it to see if it successful work or not.

What do you think is the best function to do that? fsockopen, curl or socket

What the fastest one?

Thanks.

Comment: *What the fastest one?* - TIAS (Try It And See)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the main slowdown will be actually connecting, which means that any API that supports parallel requests will allow you to run through your list faster than those who don't.

I'd suggest using `socket_create`, `socket_set_nonblock`, `socket_connect` and `socket_select` to implement this using the socket extension. You can, if you need full HTTP-support, use the multi-support of curl.

Other than that, you'll have to do as Amal Murali wrote: Try it and see.

Comment: I thought that curl is the only function which can make parallel connections because it's have multi_exec, right?

Comment: As I wrote, the socket extension allows you to process sockets in an asynchronous manner, and doesn't have all the overhead of HTTP. If it's a suitable use-case, depends on what information you want back. Set the socket to be non-blocking and use socket_select to poll for events.

Comment: If possible, could you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066722) please? thanks.